# Django For While Loops and counters when returning data

Tags: django, while-loop

I am pulling some crypto data into my web app, and placing it into bootstrap cards. My issue is with the number of cards now populating my site. So I thought, no sweat. I'll just initialize a counter at 0 and throw a while loop in there until around 9 or 10. So far no bueno, the code below is the functioning version where it just unloads unlimited crypto cards. I've tried ranges, and If anyone has an idea how I can accomplish this, it'd be greatly appreciated. I don't think it's difficult, just not making the connection. I've even found cases now where you need to register the while loop just to use it in django ? @register.tag('while') had no idea

```
              {% for x in api.Data %}
           <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="card-deck">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
            
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ x.imageurl }}" alt="{{ x.source }}">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{ x.title }}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ x.body }}</p>
                  <a href="{{ x.url}}" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</a>
                </div>
             
              </div>
              </div>
              <br />
              </div>
           
              {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the right approach. If you want less data, send less data. Don't send everything and render half of it.

This is why there is [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/):

> Django provides high-level and low-level ways to help you manage paginated data – that is, data that’s split across several pages, with “Previous/Next” links.
>
> Under the hood, all methods of pagination use the Paginator class. It does all the heavy lifting of actually splitting a QuerySet into Page objects.

And [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) also supports it.

The key difference is, that if your database has 1 million records and you render only 10, you will still fetch 1 million from the database. But if you use pagination (even if you don't need previous/next links), you only fetch 10.

Comment: Ok, so I need to change my function in my views.py. See if I can set a limit on the incoming link